# Sending backend data to Shopify

Tags: java, shopify, backend

So I have created separate backend (Java) which generates certain data. Now I want to send this data to Shopify. But I do not understand how can I do that. I must say that I have no experience with Shopify at all. Another person sets up Shopify site and he needs data generated by me. But I am so confused how to do that? Where do I start?

Comment: any api exposed to send the data ?

Comment: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify Rest API, or Shopify GraphQL API ([product api for example](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product)) allows you to send some data to Shopify store. 
Depending on your data you can use different endpoints. If you need to send some custom data, then use [metafields endpoint](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield?api[version]=2020-01) .